# GPS modem that can send data to our server

Tags: gps, device, modem

We are planning for vehicle tracking system. We would like to relay on GPS Tracking System and view position report via Google Maps.

For hardware requirement we are thinking of GPS modem that can transmit data to our system.

Which GPD Modem is suitable for my project?

Comment: There are more than 30 questions where you didn't accept an answer. It would be nice to show some appreciation for helping you out.

Answer (score 2):

Use a smartphone. Haha.

On a more serious note, since it's for vehicular application only, there are a lot of companies that manufacture GPS modules (u-blox is one of them). Just google and you'll find thousands of companies manufacturing them. But before you choose a GPS module, make sure you check the regulations of your target country. If the module works on the Iridium satellite network, countries like India & China won't allow it as Iridium frequency is close to their military frequencies. In Europe you'll be better off with the Inmarsat network. So, do your homework & you should be good.

Also, if you're developing your own map interface, you might wanna ask the manufacturer if they have any existing mapping interface you can hook into or disable. You mag be charged for either.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Are mobile networks (like GSM/GPRS/UMTS) available where you are?
if so check-out the tracking products from [this site](http://www.locationnow.com/location/FrontManage.do?activity=starfinder_global) or [this site](http://www.gpstracking.co.in/product.html) (Google keywords: GPS GPRS)

If not, you should consider a custom solution, maybe someone like [this company](http://www.novacom-services.com/content/en/) can help...

Comment: would like to follow the second option

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a project that involved sending data over GSM/CDMA network. It used a simple GSM/CDMA modem connected to an embedded linux device and was a stationary piece of hardware. Attach a GPS device and it may very well be a tracking system. The problem is when the network drops or the device moves out of the network coverage area. I am not sure if there any GSM/CDMA modem available with GPS added to them as we didn't have this facility in our hardware and it was very much desirable. We needed to use a separate GPS device, mostly iPhone, separately to determine the lat long of our device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any GSM/GPRS modem equipped with GPS device. The modem will forward the GPS data to your central server through GPRS and at the server side you just need to process rcvd data and display it on google maps.